# Unable to locate package firefox-mozilla-build

Tags: kali-linux, firefox

So I have Kali Linux installed on my Raspberry Pi 2B... and I searched up online how to install Mozilla Firefox, all of them said to uninstall iceweasel and then run the following commands:

```
apt-get remove iceweasel
echo -e "\ndeb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list > /dev/null
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C1289A29
apt-get update
apt-get install firefox-mozilla-build
```

Then after typing the last command, I then get the following error at the end:
"Unable to locate package firefox-mozilla-build"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That repository only has x86 (`i386` and `amd64`) binaries, not ARM (`armhf`) binaries.

The repository is not a place to download Firefox, it's a place to download tools to compile Firefox from source. You don't need to compile Firefox yourself, and it would probably take a very long time on a Raspberry Pi. Just install the binaries, which *are* in Kali (package name: `firefox-esr`).

Kali only ships the ESR release of Ubuntu, just like Debian. If you want the latest bugs and feature removals (but why?), get Firefox directly from the Mozilla website.

You don't appear to be very familiar with Linux. I don't recommend Kali, and especially not Kali outside of a virtual machine. Kali Linux is for experienced users who want a handy collection of network attack tools to run in a virtual machine. It is not designed to be easy to install, easy to use by Linux newbies, or to be a handy distribution to compile stuff on.

Comment: Thank you, I'm very interested in computers and all, so I decided to install Kali Linux to see if I can get any good at it, hopefully I'll get better at Linux in general. Thanks for clearing things up.